# Display driver failure (?)

Tags: linux, mac, display

I have a MacBook Air (2008) that I installed Solus (Linux) onto. In an attempt to gain control of the screen backlight (which is stuck at the extremely painful highest setting and will not respond to commands of any sort), I installed a different display driver. Now when I power up the system, it goes through the boot process and then the screen goes blank except for the blinking cursor prompt in the top left.

I've determined that the device is definitely completing the boot process, because after a length of time the cursor prompt will disappear and will reappear upon interaction.

The machine does not appear to be aware of the bootable media I've tried.

Is there anything to be done about this? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: The early MacBook Airs, iirc, needed a special USB to boot, not one you could make yourself, it was supplied with the machine. Maybe contact Apple for a replacement. 08 machines generally won't boot from USB, but the Air was the first without an optical drive, so that was the workaround. Did you try Cmd/R in case there's still a recovery partition on there?

Comment: MacOS no longer exists on the machine, so I don't know if Apple will be able or willing to help. Cmd/R didn't do anything. I wasn't sure when to do it, so I just button mashed it from power up onward.

Comment: Apple will sell you a new USB key, if you need one. I'm pretty sure if you went to an Apple Store they'd at least have a poke at it to see if it will boot from one, though idk how much further they'd help as you've got another OS on there. Any startup key combis, btw, you hit at the chimes & hold until you see evidence it did 'something'.